# jQuery is not working after div reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem.
The problem is that i'm trying to add new photo album(with jQuery) and after adding- to show new album i'm reloading DIV with jQuery .load function

```
$($classid).load('..')
```

Everything is working fine, except that after reloading function like folder hovering (where bar with buttons appear - delete,etc..on hover) just don't work.
It looks like after DIV reloading jquery is dissabled and it need's to be called out again to run all functions.

I'v tryed to add this code

```
<script>
            $.getScript("/data/sys.js" ); // item hovering functions styling etc..
            $.getScript("/data/late.js" ); //for button clicks 
</script>
```

at reload DIV'S Content..
Everything worked fine except that when I try to add new photo album at next album adding it multiply's added folder count.. so when i add one there show's up one, at next click there is two new folders.. 
I'v tryed alot and I cant figure out how to stop this or do it in diffrent way..
here is late.js file that is responsible for new folder adding..
[late.js file](http://pastebin.com/RzB2dTBK)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Does adding this code below make any difference, as the page wont load up until everything is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: Bad idea. This will only work when the page is loaded, not when the div is reloaded. It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function loadSelectors() {
   // here paste sys.js code

   $('#lfd').live('click', function(e) {//form button
     $.post( $("#frm1").attr("action"),//form
             $("#frm1 :input").serializeArray(),//form input
             function(info){
                $("#ui_info_anim_s").html(info);//popup
                $("#afolder").css("display","none");
                $("#fn_nameid").val('New Folder');
                //a lot of animation stuff for popup
                $("#ui_info_anim_s").animate({top: '40px'}, 'slow', function() {
                    $('#load_anim_privf').fadeIn( 500);
                    $('#load_anim_pubf').fadeIn( 500);
                    $('#load_anim_privf').fadeOut(1000,function(){});
                    $('#load_anim_pubf').fadeOut( 500);
                    $(this).delay(3000).animate({top: '+=40px',opacity:'0','filter':'alpha(opacity=0)'},'slow',function(){
                        $(this).css({"top": "-42px","margin-top": "-42px", "opacity": "1","filter":"alpha(opacity=0)" });


                });});

       });
       loadUp(1,'.ui_treetype','');// Reloading func

    });


    $("#frm1").submit( function() {
      return false;
    });

}
```

Now you need to call function loadSelectors() two times. First on document load & second where div created

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you attach event handlers to `div`'s and then replace them you lose all event bindings.

What you need is to attach event handlers through their parent container element which stays on page regardless of reload. I think it may be the one you refer to as `$classid` in your code.

In this case attach event handlers this way, only once, at your page dom ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $($classid).on("hover", "yourSelectorHere", function() {
       ... your code to handle event
    })

    $($classid).on("click", "yourSelectorHere", function() {
       ... your code to handle event
    })

    ...
})
```

Comment: I think we want to make sure we have `$($classid)` element there to attach `on` to it, no?

Comment: I'm sorry. You're fully right. I forgot that you still need a root element to attach bindings to. I'm deleting my silly comment ;)